# Load Custom Popup on pie click click on highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, popup, drilldown

I have a semi donut chart, in which i want to drilldown and to show a customPopup which displays a table of data. 
This is my intention to show it to my customer. can anyone help to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-drilldown/) is the highchart example of drilling down. instead showing the chart in drilldown, i want a custom popup developed in react, needs to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your highchart configuration:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    alert("test test");
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Also check this [Highchart Link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click)

Comment: can this be done dynamically with reactjs? meaning, i want to activate the click event in my react component, instead of static configurations.

Comment: I am no expert in react but `this.callingNativeMethod` might be able to call the method you want to call if you are working on the component based structure.

Comment: this also might help you [Link for react based highchart](https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts/tree/master/packages/react-jsx-highcharts)